# HDI: Constrain Property Set on Linq-To-Sql class

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

How do I constrain property setter on Linq-To-Sql class

I have a custom field that needs validation and the designer class can be over written.

I have overrider setter methods which would work but how to I restrict setting on the Linq-To-Sql class?

```
public partial class Frequency : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public void SetStartTime(TimeSpan startTime)
    {
        if(startTime.Days > 0){throw new Exception("No day value is valid for start time value";}
        this._StartTime = string.Format("{0}:hh\\:mm\\:ss", startTime);
    }
    public TimeSpan GetStartTime()
    {
        IEnumerable<int> startTime = this._StartTime.Split(':').Cast<int>();
        return new TimeSpan(startTime.ElementAt<int>(0), startTime.ElementAt<int>(1), startTime.ElementAt<int>(2));
    }
}
```

Comment: one of my ideas on this was to write a facade wrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ 2 SQL has everything you need to overcome this problem if you use the LINQ to SQL Classes designer.

Let's say your table has a column "Number" of type Int32.
The designer will create:

Field -> _Number

Property -> Number

Method -> OnNumberChanging(int value)

Method -> OnNumberChanged()

The last 2 methods are partial. This means you don't have to touch the designer generated files in case you refresh your classes from the database.

By creating the following in another file:

```
public partial class MyLinqToSqlClass
{
    partial void OnNumberChanging(int value)
    {
        //your code here
        //throw exception if necessary when validating
    }
}
```

you get what you need.

This piece of code gets called inside the set method of the Number property right before the value of the field gets changed.

This way you don't worry about using the set method of the property.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good point!  Linq-To-Sql classes implement INotifyPropertyChanged and I can override or partial add to the OnChange method!